# How to handle a async function inside double forEach?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I have code like this inside my `componentDidMount`

```
arrayDate.forEach( (date) => {
    var tempData = []
    anotherArray.forEach(async(event) => {
      if(event.local_date == date){
        const groupNew = await this.getGroupDetailInfo(event.group.urlname)
        event.newGroup = groupNew
        tempData.push(event)
      }
    })
    let tempObj = {
      title: date, 
      data: tempData
    }
    newEvent.push(tempObj)
  })
getGroupDetailInfo = async(urlname) => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(`https://api.meetup.com/${urlname}`);
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      return responseJson;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

When I `console.log` the state the data will be get, but in rendering, there's a delay that cause the data sometimes shown and sometimes not... I have search that there's problem in using `async` in `forEach`.. But I'm still stuck, please help me...

Comment: The approach seem not to be correct. 
you are using a foreach to do two jobs: 1) filter local_date == date and 2) enriching the event object with more info. 

I suggest a cleaner approach: first use .filter() to remove undesired events, then use .map() to enrich the event. 

.map might have issues with async, a safer approach is just using a for loop which I remember being more resilient. In alternative you should try async iterators which seem to be the right solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the componentDidMount function will not wait for inner forEach to complete and elements with empty data will get pushed to newEvent (Although you waited for each operation inside of foreach, there is no way for waiting for the foreach loop as a whole)
So you can do one of two ways

First, use map to convert another array to an array of promises and use Promise.all to wait for every promise to complete
Caution: Throwing in each of promises will cause the whole promise to become rejected
So it will look like this:

```
arrayDate.forEach(date => {
  Promise.all(
    anotherArray.map(
      event => (event.local_date === date ? this.getGroupDetailInfo(event.group.urlname) : Promise.resolve()),
    )
  ).then(groupsArray => groupsArray.filter(g => g.newGroup))
   .then(groupsArray => newEvent.push({ title: date, data: groupsArray }));
});
```

Second, we can make our componentDidMount function async, and use a normal for loop for iterating the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own implementation of `forEach` that supports async/await for that. I've written a tiny snippet for you:

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
    try {
        for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            await callback(array[index], index, array);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error in asyncForEach: ", e);
    }
}
```

Refactor your code to use it like that:

```
await asyncForEach(arrayDate, async date => {
    var tempData = []
    await asyncForEach(anotherArray, async event => {
      if(event.local_date == date){
        const groupNew = await this.getGroupDetailInfo(event.group.urlname)
        event.newGroup = groupNew
        tempData.push(event)
      }
    })
    let tempObj = {
      title: date, 
      data: tempData
    }
    newEvent.push(tempObj)
})
```

Just keep in mind that you have to execute that code inside an `async function`